# Using Workspace Variables in Jenkins XUnit Custom Stylesheet

Tags: environment-variables, stylesheet, jenkins, xunit

I searched around for a while and have not found an answer to this question. I am using Jenkins to do some testing and I use Clearcase as my CM tool. The stylesheet I have created for a custom tool lives in a directory relative to the clearcase view path. When I hardcode the entire path to the stylesheet, everything is fine, but if I try to use the ${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME} environment variable, xUnit does not try to resolve it, rather it gives me the error that

```
"The input xsl '${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME}/rest_of_path/my_stylesheet.xsl' relative to the workspace '/myworkspace' doesn't exist."
```

The strange thing is that I also use this variable to point to where the xml file is and it finds it with no problem. Does anyone know if that is a specific "feature" of the xUnit plugin or if it is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

See pushy's answer to my other post at [Hudson/Jenkins PMD Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950255/hudson-jenkins-pmd-configuration)

Your clearcase path needs to be specified in the main Jenkins configuration.

Comment: Pulak, thanks for the update. I went and took a look at pushy's answer to your question and I think my issue might be slightly different. I have set the 'Use Custom Workspace' variable to a specific directory on my hard drive and am using the Clearcase plugin to create a snapshot view in this directory. The clearcase plugin generates a copy of all of my code to the /{workspace}/${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME}/source dir. My issue is that I want to create additional directories at the same level as source (such as test). (Continued ...)

Comment: I don't want to set the full path in the workspace to /{workspace}/${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME} because then the I get /{workspace}/${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME}/${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME}/source from the clearcase plugin. I want to maintain the new dir's I create relative to ${CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME} in case I have multiple snapshot views all using the same /{workspace} dir.

Answer (score 0):

Bug.

(or unimplemented feature)

I have run into the same scenario using the Jenkins XUnit plugin, where the "Custom Tool Pattern" value containing a Global Parameters IS being resolved, but the "Custom Stylesheet" value containing a Global Parameters is NOT resolved, leading to an error similar to yours.

Having a peek at the source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/xunit-plugin/ reveals that the Global Parameter resolution for the XLS parameter is not yet implemented.

A bug has been filed here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17438/

Since it's open source, it's time to get Maven installed and debug some Jenkins plugin code.

UPDATE: and done, you should see the new functionality in the latest version