# Hudson/Jenkins PMD Configuration

Tags: ant, hudson, jenkins, pmd

I am new to Jenkins and just started configuring it. This is what i have done till now:

1. Installed and configured Jenkins to display the home page. Added PMD plugin.
2. Set the `HUDSON_HOME` to a specific directory > C:\Work\Jenkins
3. Configured a test build to run a simple do-nothing ant script. It runs successfully
4. Written an independent `pmdbuild.xml` to run checks on a set of files in C:\myview (I am using clearcase). This xml also copies the output pmd_results.xml to the workspace directory in `$HUDSON_HOME/[job-name]/workspace`
5. Now I added the `pmdbuild.xml` as a step in my primary build. So my build has 2 steps:
   a. Run a simple script, do-nothing.
   b. Run p`mdbuild.xml` which generate `pmd_results.xml` and place it in `$HUDSON_HOME/[job-name]/workspace` (HARD-CODED as Jenkins PMD plugin expects the file there)
6. Jenkins picks up the `pmd_results.xml` automatically with the plugin and displays warnings and everything.

Now the problem:

- If I click on a filename in the PMD results, it gives a `filenotfound` exception as it is looking for the source file in `$HUDSON_HOME/[job-name]/workspace`.
- My java code files are placed in C:\myview (a clearcase snapshot view)

My question is, do I need all my code files to be present inside `$HUDSON_HOME/[job-name]/workspace` ?? Meaning can't I tell Jenkins to look for the PMD input files in C:\myview or any other directory instead of `$HUDSON_HOME/[job-name]/workspace` ??

Sorry for the extremely long description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins expects that all the code is in the workspace. Usually Jenkins is used to check out a copy of the code into the workspace, and then runs all build steps on the Sources in the Workspace.

Might seem restraining at first, but it saves you a lot of trouble if you need to move Jenkins to another server, or create a slave instance.

So I would suggest you let Jenkins check out your code (there should be a clearcase plugin) into the workspace, and run the analysis on the checked out code.

If there are compelling reasons why your code has to stay where it is (C:\myview in your case) you can still set the workspace of your build to that directory (find this in the job configuration page, you need to click on the 'extended' button to see the option).

Comment: thanks many.. I found out the option in master Jenkins config and fixed the problem. Don't agree with the Jenkins checking out my code though completely. It should be more of a case to case basis than anything and not a compulsion.

Comment: Of course not every job should check out sources. It makes a lot of sense to have one job which checks out the sources and builds them, another which performs tests on the build sources, another which performs some code analysis. However, it still is best practice to have Jenkins check out the sources, and not do it outside of Jenkins. If you check out the sources with Jenkins, you will get many advantages (like history keeping of which source changes were used in which build etc.).

Comment: I did have a reason to not check-out as my source code contains 40K+ files and clearcase is not git :)